# Sticky sidebar scrolling lag and infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have a sidebar that scrolls down with the page. However, the sidebar seems to lag behind the scrolling of the page, ex. scroll down and sidebar shows up a few seconds later. Also, the sidebar will keep going down, making the page longer, and causing the footer to become inaccessible. What do I need to do to make the sidebar move with the scroll and for the sidebar to stop moving at the footer? Here is my jQuery code:

```
            $(function() {

                var $sidebar   = $("aside"), 
                    $window    = $(window),
                    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
                    topPadding = 50;

                $window.scroll(function() {
                    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                        });
                    } else {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: 0
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
```

An example can be seen at http://meddiary.com/plans-pricing/. Fixing the code is welcomed but just pointing me in the right direction is the best.

Comment: Have you considered using Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Comment: Not really. I'm using jQuery and have plenty of functions already using it. What's the advantage in your opinion?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap is a collection of jQuery plugins as well as a CSS framework. An alternative would be to just use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed my issue:

```
            if ($(window).width() > 767) {

                var $sidebar   = $("aside"), 
                    $window    = $(window),
                    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
                    topPadding = 50;

                $window.scroll(function() {
                    if($window.scrollTop() > $('h3').offset().top) {
                        $sidebar.stop().css('marginTop', '680px');              
                    } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                        }, 100, function() {
                        });
                    } else {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: 0
                        });
                    }
                });

            };
```

`if ($(window).width() > 767)` part keeps the sidebar from scrolling if the viewport is wider than 767px. `if($window.scrollTop() > $('h3').offset().top) { $sidebar.stop().css('marginTop', '680px'); }` part is for when the top of the viewport hits the desired element, `h3`, the scrolling stops. That part must be first because the `else if` statement is always true! Then I just reduced the animation time to stop the lagging.

Answer (score 0):

Try solving it with pure CSS:

```
.affix {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Or you can use an existing jQuery plugin like this one:
http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/

Comment: I tried that originally but `position:fixed;` doesn't really keep the sidebars in the correct horizontal position.